A game where you are given choice to either double or triple, then zeroes in the digits are removed
In this game, the player can choose weather to apply $x \rightarrow \text{Noz}(2x)$ or $x \rightarrow \text{Noz}(3x)$, where the function $\text{Noz}(n)$ removes zero digits from $n$. The game begins with an initial value of $1$. The player goal is to maximize the final value after some number of moves, $k$. The key to this game is to double or triple in such a way that avoids zero digits, as a removal of even just a single digit is enough to undo the growth from doubling/tripling. Obviously, with more digits, it can be harder to avoid zero digits. Let $a(k)$ be the largest number that can be reached with $k$ moves. For $0≤k<20$, here are the values of $a(k)$:
$1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683, 39366, 78732, 236196, 472392, 1417176, 4251528, 12754584, 38263752, 114791256, 344373768$
(This also to happens to be a valid and an optimal path for $k=19$).
It seems to me that the sequence doesn't have a finite upper bound. Interestingly, $a(19) = a(21) = 344,373,768$ and $a(20) = a(22) = 688,747,536$. However, this pattern break with $a(23) = 1,239,746,148$ and the sequence starts growing again. Can anyone prove/disprove the existence of a finite upper bound to $a(k)$?

It is strange to have $a(21)=a(19)$. What is the definition of $a(n)$ ; $a(n)=$ the maximum integer we can reach with exactly $n$ moves ? or $a(n)=$ the maximum integer we can reach with at most $n$ moves ?  Edit : with both definitions, this result is strange.

@Lorrran  Yes, it is quite bizzare. And to clarify, $a(n)$ is the maximum integer that can be reached with exactly $n$ moves

Ok ... $a(19)= 344373768$ and the list of steps is 1 3 9 18 54 162 486 1458 4374 8748 26244 78732 236196 472392 1417176 4251528 12754584 38263752 114791256 344373768 ; for $a(21)$, the road is very similar ; we just have 2 more steps at the beginning : 1 3 9 18 36 18 54 ... ; the particularity is that when $x=18$, $Noz_3( Noz_2(x))=x$

With more computational effort, I found that the $k=57$ is the first time that $a(k) < 2^k$. $a(57) = 77747669189897472$

I am sure the sequence has a finite upper bound.  If it somehow got to hundreds of digits there would "always" be at least one zero in both the double and the triple.  That brings the number down by more than a factor three.  The next iteration will have the same problem and you will come back to small numbers.

I disagree. Imagine the upper bound is $L$, with $d$d digits. Between $\frac{L}{2}$ and $L$, the number of integers is $\frac{L}{2}$ ; the numbers of integer that can be reached is ??? Impossible to calculate, but we can estimate greater than $\frac{L}{2} \times 0.9^d /1000 $ ; Each of these numbers has a probability $0.9^d$ to have none $0$ when we multiply by 2 , and same when we multiply by 3. So the numbers of couples (a,2a) or (a,3a) with a<L<2a or a<L<3a, and 2a or 3a valid ( without any $0$) is very big.

I have done some tests. For performance, I don't evaluate all numbers. At each step, I keep only the 100 biggest numbers, and I explore the 200 numbers that we can obtain. So I am not sure to have the best result. At step 126, my biggest number is 125382544619867788368384 ; after that, there is no improvment before step 3650 ! and I obtain 157347356321746792679976 ; and still very few  improvments, until step 31383, with number 1255151871197518589853696 and step 31386 with number 1363478168155533461737128 (25 digits).

Something like 400000 more steps, and my upper bound is now 8459843298593268937926528 (still 25 digits). It is totally clear for me that there is no finite upper bound for this process.

@BryleMorga How could you compute $a(57)$ ? Does that not basically require to check $2^{57}$ sequences ?

@Peter What i would do is store all of number reachable by $k$-steps. Then what i would do is generate the set of all numbers reachable by $(k+1)$-steps from that. There would be a lot of duplicates so the size of set won't "fully" double.  (basidally exploiting the fact that lots of sequences of same lengths lead to same number)
